# slight changes in long lat for varations of point with the same location

Tags: c#, algorithm

Bit of a weird one this. I'm rendering datasets on a map and need to split out points that have exactly the same long and lat. I had the idea of grouping my dataset by long and lat and where they are the same adjusting slightly so that they are visible as seperate entities on the map - rather than overlapping.

I'm using linq to group them and then enumerating my grouped items and I'd like to spiral the adjusted points around the orginal point (this is a requirement as I may have a few hundred points that are the same geographically) so that they spread out from the original point.

Does anyone know of a simple calculation i can add to my loop to adjust the items in this manner.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The math behind this is pretty simple. A circle can be represented by the sine function in the x-axis and the cosine function in the y-axis. Here's some pseudo-code:

```
int num = OverlappingPoints.Length;
for(int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
{
    int radius = 50;

    // using 2*pi because most math functions use radians... change 2*pi to 360 if your math library uses 360 degrees instead of 2*pi radians to represent a circle.
    Map.Plot(OverlappingPoints[i].Latitude + radius*sin(2*pi*i/num),
        OverlappingPoints[i].Latitude + radius*cos(2*pi*i/num));
}
```

That pseudo-code, if properly implemented, will draw the points out in a circle around the original point. Change the radius multiplier to the sine and cosine functions if you want to increase the radius of the circle. **If you want the points to spiral out instead of making a circle**, choose a number of points per circle revolution and replace `num` with that number in the sin/cos functions. Also, increase the radius after each loop iteration, probably by using a number and multiplying it by the loop index. (i.e. you could change `radius` to `50*i`).

Hope this helps.